# how to notify error for `restart: on-failure` in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I prepared such docker-compose.yml

```
  server:
    build: server
    restart: on-failure
```

And, I want to send error from shell script **inside container** to restart container.
How can I do that?

Comment: By default it restarts container, what do you mean by so?

Comment: On this container, shell script is running to detect something.
And I want to restart server container themselves by shell script.

Comment: You mean you want to restart container by itself?

Comment: I mean, I want to restart container by themselves somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Containers are not VMs, they are processes (in one way of thinking). Thus, an OS restart within a container doesn't make sense and is therefore not possible. One kills, stops, or restarts containers, e.g.

```
docker stop CONTAINER
docker kill CONTAINER
docker restart CONTAINER
```

In the context of your question, and depending on the specifics of your container, it probably makes the most sense to restart the container in question.

So I think the best solution for your scenario is to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` inside your container and use Docker API to restart your container by itself.

You can see a list of libraries and SDKs which may help you in [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdks/). Be sure to install your specific SDK inside your container in order to use it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Iman,
I tried it and called API from inside container.
```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.30/containers/xxxxx/restart?t=5
```
That error occurred.
```
curl: option --unix-socket: is unknown
```

Comment: The problem is that you should mount it using `-v` option. For example `docker run sth -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` @Harry.

Comment: I'm using docker-compose
And then added it like this

`- /private/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in volumes directive.

Comment: Changing the order to sth like this won't help? `curl -X POST --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock`